# Strange bug with Streams

Tags: java, junit, set, java-stream

So I have created my own Set, which is just a regular set, but has additional functions (for example my set only stores absolute values).

Here is my Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {

private Set<Integer> mySet;

public SortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet() {
    mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mySet.size();
}
@Override
public boolean add(E e){
    return mySet.add(Math.abs((Integer) e));
}


@Override
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    return mySet.remove(o);
}

@Override
public boolean contains(Object o){
    return mySet.contains(o);
}

@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object e: c) {
        myList.add(Math.abs((Integer) e));
    }
    return mySet.addAll(myList);
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return mySet.toString();
}

}
```

I had a test case in JUnit, which failed. Because there was some issue with my code. For demonstration purpose, and for me to explain my issue better I have created two functions, which show the problem well.

Here is the problem:

```
public static void testSortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet() {
    Set<Integer> set1 = new SortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet();
    Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>();
    set1.add(5);
    set1.add(3);
    set2.add(5);
    set2.add(3);
    String x = toString(set1); //x is  ""
    String t = toString(set2); //t is "3 5"
}

public static String toString(final Collection<Integer> collection) {
    return String.join(" ", collection.stream()
            .map(i -> Integer.toString(i))
            .toArray(String[]::new));
}
```

So the problem arises in this line:

```
String x = toString(set1); //x is always an empty string
String t = toString(set2); //t works correctly
```

When I go through debugger I see that String x is always an empty String and String t works correctly. By the way set1 is representation of my created set and set2 is just a regular hashset.

The question is: how can I fix my SortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet class so that the toString() method worked fine with my own created set as well.

P.S I am new to streams and I don't really understand the problem, why does it happens.

Comment: You do not delegate all methods implemented by HashSet to `mySet`. For instance `splitIerator` might be used by `stream()`. Tip: either the IDE can create delegates, or you override and edit them super -> mySet.

Comment: I just wanted to have only these methods overriden in my set. for it to work i should add splitIerator set also?

Comment: Actually better all methods that might get be called on your set object. At least of HashSet, the class. Otherwise you have an empty set delegating to mySet, but if one original method accesses the empty set, you are in trouble.

Comment: Could you please show me the correct way to write iterator method in this case? i would really appreciate.

Comment: `return mySet.iterator();` simple

Comment: it gives me an error. it says required Iterator<E>, provided Iterator<Integer>

Comment: `public class SortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet extends HashSet<Integer> {` Sorry did not see, and already there is a full answer of @BorisAzanov. Good luck

Comment: Could you perhaps try to rename to a more descriptive question? It's not really a bug in streams :-) Think something that would help someone who would search for a similar problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Tomas F gave better [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677229/strange-bug-with-streams#answer-68677379)

Main problem in your set is using `HashSet mySet` as field and extending `HashSet`. In java better to use (field) composition instead of extending to add some functionality to your class. Here you tried use both - it's not a good idea.
Best decision is to use just composition and extending more general class, for example `AbstractSet<Integer>` and `Set<Integer>`:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class SortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet extends AbstractSet<Integer> 
        implements Set<Integer>, java.io.Serializable {

    private final Set<Integer> mySet;

    public SortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet() {
        mySet = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return mySet.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mySet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer e) {
        return mySet.add(Math.abs(e));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return mySet.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return mySet.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Integer> c) {
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer e : c) {
            myList.add(Math.abs(e));
        }
        return mySet.addAll(myList);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mySet.toString();
    }
}
```

in this case you don't have to implement `spliterator`, because `Set` has default implementation using `this` keyword (which is refer to your set as a `Collection`)

but also you can implement spliterator in your class (but using such `extends` and internal `Set` fields are the bad practice. Also, it's better to get rid of type parameter `E` and casting elements to Integer:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class SortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet extends HashSet<Integer> {

    private Set<Integer> mySet;

    public SortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet() {
        mySet = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mySet.size();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer e){
        return mySet.add(Math.abs(e));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return mySet.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o){
        return mySet.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Integer> c) {
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer e: c) {
            myList.add(Math.abs(e));
        }
        return mySet.addAll(myList);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return mySet.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<Integer> spliterator() {
        return mySet.spliterator();
    }

}
```

Comment: works! thank you. So the problem happened, because i didn't override spliterator method?

Comment: When you extend `AbstractSet`, you don’t need to override `addAll`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're extending HashSet but also using an internal Set.

When adding, you're adding to the internal Set but when using collection.stream() it calls the inherited HashSet (which is empty).

Easiest for you I beleive would be to remove the internal 'mySet' and call the inherited methods in your overridden methods.

For instance, your add method would be

```
@Override
public boolean add(E e){
    return super.add(Math.abs((Integer) e));
}
```

(and then you don't need to override size, remove, contains of toString or spliterator)

Full example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortedByAbsoluteValueIntegerSet extends HashSet<Integer> {


    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer e){
        return super.add(Math.abs(e));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Integer> c) {
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer e: c) {
            myList.add(Math.abs(e));
        }
        return super.addAll(myList);
    }

}
```

Comment: how can i fix it i dont really understand

Comment: In your case i would guess the easiest would be to remove the internal private Set<Integer> mySet; and call the inherited methods in your overridden methods.

Comment: then i won't have access to mySet, and i wont be able to manipluate logic for absolute integers

Comment: yes, you still override the add methods where you can manipulate the incoming values